# How to go from $\frac{a}{sinA}=\frac{b}{sinB}=\frac{c}{sinC}=2R$ to $sinA+sinB+sinC=\frac{a+b+c}{2R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**
I was wondering how to get from
$\frac{a}{sinA}=\frac{b}{sinB}=\frac{c}{sinC}=2R$ to $sinA+sinB+sinC=\frac{a+b+c}{2R}$
I was reading up a proof and I didn't know how the author went to the conclusion

I didn't understand on how the author went to that conclusion

I tried to multiply sinA sinB SinC on both sides in the equation $\frac{a}{sinA}=\frac{b}{sinB}=\frac{c}{sinC}=2R$ but it just got too messy and it didn't work out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following equations

$\sin A=\frac{a}{2R}$

$\sin B=\frac{b}{2R}$

$\sin C=\frac{c}{2R}$

Answer (score 3):

If $\frac x y = \frac z k$ then $\frac x y = \frac z k = \frac {x +z} {y+k}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a=2R \sin A, \;b=2R \sin B, \;c = 2R \sin C$, so $\;a+b+c=\dots$.